# username and password help in joomla

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0, login-script

What I'm trying to do here is display my login information and once logged in display something else

Example is here

```
    <?php
    $user = JFactory::getUser();
    $status = $user->guest;

    if($status == 1){
    echo '
   <form id="login-form" class="form-inline" method="post" action="/home">
   <div class="topUser">
        Name: 
        <input id="modlgn-username" class="TopinputReg" type="text" placeholder="User Name" tabindex="0" name="username" />
      </div>
      <div class="toppass">Password: 
        <input id="modlgn-passwd" class="TopinputReg" type="password" placeholder="Password" tabindex="0" name="password" pwfprops="," />
      </div>
      <div class="topsignin">
        <input class="Signin" name="Submit" tabindex="0" type="submit" value="" />
      </div>
      <div class="topregister">
        <a href="http://gamers-league.com/forums/user/register"><input name="button" type="submit" class="Register" id="button" value="" /></a>
              </div>
    <input type="hidden" value="com_users" name="option">
    <input type="hidden" value="user.login" name="task">
    <input type="hidden" value="aW5kZXgucGhwP0l0ZW1pZD0xMzM=" name="return">
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="39ea5446d876078c6f6221d396ef5bd4">
              </form>
    ';
     }
    else
    {
    echo '
    <div class="topUser">Welcome Back!</div>
      <div class="toppass">Enjoy you stay.</div>
      <form id="login-form" class="form-vertical" method="post" action="/log-out">
      <div class="topsignin">
        <input class="Signout" type="submit" value="" name="Submit" />
        <input type="hidden" value="com_users" name="option">
              </div>
    <input type="hidden" value="com_users" name="option">
    <input type="hidden" value="user.logout" name="task">
    <input type="hidden" value="aW5kZXgucGhwP0l0ZW1pZD0xMDE=" name="return">
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="994c61f8ab4ccf23fe9dae6546a87089">

      </form>
      <div class="topregister">
        <a href="http://gamers-league.com/forums/user"><input name="button" type="submit" class="account" id="button" value="" /></a>
      </div>
    ';
    }
    ?>
```

No I know what I am doing wrong just have no clue how to fix it. the two

need to have  a different generated number each time but how do i do this.

since this numbers are the same every time if i log in then out then try to log back in it will give me "Invalid Token"

When i go into the login template it gives me 
this for login

```
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo base64_encode($this->params->get('login_redirect_url', $this->form->getValue('return'))); ?>" />
<?php echo JHtml::_('form.token'); ?>
```

and this for log out

```
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo base64_encode($this->params->get('logout_redirect_url', $this->form->getValue('return'))); ?>" />
<?php echo JHtml::_('form.token'); ?>
```

Now if I replace the hidden fields that already have the pregenerated numbers with the php stuff above when i try to refresh my page it goes completely blank.

I am at a loss with this see as how I am not very advanced in php. any help anyone cant provide would be massively helpful..

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? If you are not that experienced in PHP the last thing you want to do is to play around with passwords. Are you just trying to display something to users when they have logged in?

Comment: im trying to display login and register and if there logged in there is an option to log out or account.

Answer (score 0):

why not try like this,

```
  <?php
    $user = JFactory::getUser();
    $status = $user->guest;

    if($status == 1):
?>

<form id="login-form" class="form-inline" method="post" action="/home">
   <div class="topUser">
        Name: 
        <input id="modlgn-username" class="TopinputReg" type="text" placeholder="User Name" tabindex="0" name="username" />
      </div>
      <div class="toppass">Password: 
        <input id="modlgn-passwd" class="TopinputReg" type="password" placeholder="Password" tabindex="0" name="password" pwfprops="," />
      </div>
      <div class="topsignin">
        <input class="Signin" name="Submit" tabindex="0" type="submit" value="" />
      </div>
      <div class="topregister">
        <a href="http://gamers-league.com/forums/user/register"><input name="button" type="submit" class="Register" id="button" value="" /></a>
              </div>
    <input type="hidden" value="com_users" name="option">
    <input type="hidden" value="user.login" name="task">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo base64_encode($this->params->get('login_redirect_url', $this->form->getValue('return'))); ?>" />
<?php echo JHtml::_('form.token'); ?>
              </form>

<?php else:
?>

<div class="topUser">Welcome Back!</div>
      <div class="toppass">Enjoy you stay.</div>
      <form id="login-form" class="form-vertical" method="post" action="/log-out">
      <div class="topsignin">
        <input class="Signout" type="submit" value="" name="Submit" />
        <input type="hidden" value="com_users" name="option">
              </div>
    <input type="hidden" value="com_users" name="option">
    <input type="hidden" value="user.logout" name="task">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo base64_encode($this->params->get('logout_redirect_url', $this->form->getValue('return'))); ?>" />
<?php echo JHtml::_('form.token'); ?>

      </form>
      <div class="topregister">
        <a href="http://gamers-league.com/forums/user"><input name="button" type="submit" class="account" id="button" value="" /></a>
      </div>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: check my edit the logout url placed correctly, Also what exactly your requirement ?

Comment: ok i updated it with what you did and still it blanks out the rest of the content after the php. What I'm trying to do is make it were people can log in and if they are logged in it will display logout and account. this is what its supposed to look like only work. the one im linking is just css and not a real login http://gamers-league.com/wild-star-home

Comment: ok , instead of checking guest status try something like if((int)$user->id == 0) rest of the things are correct.

Comment: Turn your error reporting to development (in global configuration).